Why my 2D sprite will leave a trace in the canvas?
This is the movement script
if (waypoints == null || waypoints.Length == 0) return;
        Transform targetWaypoint = waypoints[currentWaypointIndex];
        Vector2 direction = (targetWaypoint.position - transform.position).normalized;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, targetWaypoint.position) < 0.1f)
        {
            currentWaypointIndex++;
            if (currentWaypointIndex >= waypoints.Length)
            {
                currentWaypointIndex = 0; 
            }
        }

canvas settings:

solve method and reasons

if something leaves a trace it's probably more an issue with a Camera Clear flag

It would be more precise if you add a screenshot of 'trace'.
Check if Camera- Environment- Background Type is set to Uninitialized.
Change it to Solid Color or Skybox might solve your problem.
